# Using C-String and Pointers. Remove any characters except small cases and whitespaces

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

We were asked to create a program that will remove any characters from the given string except the small letters and white space (using pointers).

Example:

> Enter a String: Hi there are #20 markers points to NORTH.
>
> Output: i there are markers points to

This is what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

void lowerCase(char *text);

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin.getline(str, 100);
    lowerCase(str);
    std::cout << "\nOutput after lowerCase():\n";
    std::cout << str;

    system("pause>0");
    return 0;
}

void lowerCase(char *text)
{
    while (*text != '\0') {
        if (((unsigned int)*text >= 97 && (unsigned int)*text <= 122) || *text == ' ') {
            text++;
        }
        else {
            for (char *i = text; *i != '\0'; i++) {
                *i = *(i + 1);
            }
            text++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code has an output of:

> Enter a String: Hi there are #20 markers points to NORTH.
>
> Output after lowerCase():
>
> i there are 2 markers points to OT.

How can I achieve the result in the example?

Comment: Use `std::string` rather than `char[]` or `char*` in c++, period!

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: @manni66 completely depends on what is the aim of the lesson. The aim of this one obviously is not to learn c++, but maybe pointers and loops.

Comment: Since @user9212993 already mentioned the usage of `std::string`, I will add something to the 'good practices': use `static_cast` instead of c-style casts. `static_cast<unsigned>(*text)` is infinitely more readable than `(unsigned int)*text` **and** is safer

Comment: "Today we'll be learning C++ by starting with C" is *not* how you do it. C++ is a different language, it has different approaches to solving problems, and one of the best things about C++ is you don't have to use `char*`.

Comment: @tobi303 yes, learn pointer and loop, then string and vector. YAIT.

Comment: @manni66 Nice acronym I have to remember for future ;-)

Comment: @tobi303 "The aim of this one obviously is not to learn c++, but maybe pointers and loops" Are not loops and pointers very important part of C++ are they?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Regarding pointers for advanced students maybe, certainly not for beginners lessons.

Comment: @user9212993 I do not agree entirely.

Comment: @Vlad So we can agree to disagree. I'm really tired of hitting those _"well taught"_ apprentices at my workplace, and totally brain-wash them before I even consider to unleash them working with our production code :-P ...

Comment: @tadman `char*` here is just an iterator. `\0` is the end iterator. I think it is OK to use iterators in C++.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like 97 and 122.  If you mean `'a'`, just state `'a'`, not 97.  Also, that test for lower case, even if you stated 'a' and 'z' is *not* the way to do this.  There is a `islower` function that a programmer should use, since it is the system you're working on that knows what a lower-case character consists of, instead of the programmer assuming what is lower case.   Not every environment is English, and not every computer uses ASCII.  You're being taught so many wrong things by your teacher.

Comment: Also, a white space includes tabs and other characters.  It isn't just the "normal" space.  Again, use the function `isspace()`, and don't assume that the space character is the only whitespace character.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes of course they are. I take your comment as supporting my point. To become a C++ programmer imho it is more important to know vectors than to know raw arrays, but in reality not all C++ code is vectors and unicorns and purple elephants but sometimes one has to deal with nasty apis or legacy code. Just to avoid a misunderstanding: I am aware that there is a big problem with the way how c++ is thought, but I am certain that this cannot be fixed by a demonization of any c++ lesson that contains raw pointers or c-arrays

Comment: I am sorry if this question triggered some people here. I am just a beginner at programming, and our professor just asked us to write a program similar to this. Though he did not say if we have to use c-string or string. He just want to see the use of pointer though. But he hasn't thought us yet about iterators and such, so I couldn't think of anyway but to use c-string. By the way, I used the erase-remove_if idiom from the code below but why is it giving me an output of: "i there are markers points to to NORTH."

Comment: *He just want to see the use of pointer though.* -- All of the answers given uses pointers.  The problem with saying "use pointers" is that we have no idea of what *extent* to use pointers.  Declare pointers?  Or have pointers just "show up" naturally (like in the answers given)?  The name of an array is a pointer to the first element when passed to a function -- does that count?  A teacher just saying "I want to see pointer usage" sorry to say, doesn't know C++ or even 'C', as they would never say just that -- they would outline *exacty* where / when they want to "see pointers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `lowerCase()` leapfrogs over consecutive characters that should be removed; you can see this if you logically trace through the else-block:

```
else {
    for (char *i = text; *i != '\0'; i++) {
        *i = *(i + 1);
    }
    text++; // <- this always skips the next character
}
```

You don't need `text++` in the else-block since `*i = *(i + 1)` already copies the next character into the position pointed to by `text`.

Comment: Don't encourage the OP going that way further please! Wanna be a _YAIT_? Then maybe do so.

Comment: @user9212993 it's not the student you are at war with. It's the teacher. The student's the victim here, and they still have to pass the class, so cut them some slack.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, yeah! They're producing _"cannon fodder"_ it seems. That has to stop! Universities and schools need to adapt to the requirements in _real world_ software industries. Unless that step is taken, I'm not really agreeing that my income tax payments are wasted for that shit!

Comment: Bub, I know the pain. Last week I did a round of interviewing comp sci grads.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-start from scratch. @frslm shows you the issue, but as many other pointed out, that's not the competent teacher's way.

Consider this:

- Create the return string.
- Scan the input string.
- For each character, decide if you keep it or not.
- If you keep it, append it to the return string.
- Return the return string.

Also,

- don't hardcode 97 and 122. use 'a', 'z', or is_lower() or, etc...

Your code will be stronger, easier to maintain, nicer.

Answer (score 1):

When you decide to remove a character from the string, you shift the remaining characters one position to the left, which is fine, but you then skip the character at the position that follows the start of the shifted characters, regardless of what its value actually is.  That is why you are seeing unwanted characters in the output.  Simply don't increment the pointer after the shift, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

void removeIfNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(char *text);

int main()
{
    char str[100];

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin.getline(str, 100);

    removeIfNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(str);

    std::cout << "\nOutput after lowerCase():\n";
    std::cout << str;

    std::system("pause>0");
    return 0;
}

void removeIfNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(char *text)
{
    while (*text != '\0') {
        if (std::islower(*text) || std::isspace(*text)) {
            ++text;
        }
        else {
            for (char *i = text; *i != '\0'; ++i) {
                *i = *(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, with that said, this approach is really the C way of doing things!  Since you are clearly using C++, the C++ way would be to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with [C++ standard library algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), like [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) (using the so-called [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool isNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(char c);

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    str.erase(
        std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
            isNotLowercaseOrWhitespace
            /* alternatively, in C++11 and later:
            [](char c){ return !(std::islower(c) || std::isspace(c)); }
            */
        )
    );

    std::cout << "\nOutput after lowerCase():\n";
    std::cout << str;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

bool isNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(char c)
{
    return !(std::islower(c) || std::isspace(c));
}
```

Or, make a new `std::string` that contains a copy of the characters you want to keep, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::string removeAllNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(const std::string &s);

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    str = removeAllNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(str);

    std::cout << "\nOutput after lowerCase():\n";
    std::cout << str;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

std::string removeAllNotLowercaseOrWhitespace(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(str.size());

    for(std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin(); iter != str.end(); ++iter) {
        char c = *iter;
        if (std::islower(c) || std::isspace(c)) {
            ret.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    /* alternatively, in C++11 and later:
    std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(ret),
        [](char c){ return (std::islower(c) || std::isspace(c)); }
    );
    */

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: When I use the erase-remove_if idiom code that you have given, why is it giving me an output of: "i there are  markers points to to NORTH."